# How to get only phone number not email address in a query

Tags: sql-server

Hi guys I have a code in which i am taking X and Y As phone number.

X Datatype varchar(10)
Y Datatype varchar(100)

Now in Y column i have email address to so my query is how can i take only X+y As phone number but when Y is email address then i don't pick that row data.

```
Select * from a.cus as cus_num, b.X+''+b.Y As phone number from table
```

Their is more code for a and b but that is not relevant here so i didn't post it.

Example data:

```
cus     X    Y
123     12   21
234     21   xyz@gmail.com
```

So i want to pick only first cus number not the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a not like statement with a wildcard in it:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

```
 Select * from a.cus as cus_num, b.X+''+b.Y As phone number from table where b.Y NOT LIKE('%@%')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for `@` in the Y column:

```
select a.cus as cus_num, 
    b.X + '' + b.Y as phone number
from table
where Y not like '%@%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT CONCAT(X,Y) AS PhoneNumber FROM table WHERE Y NOT LIKE '%@%'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use REGEXP

```
SELECT CONCAT(X,Y) As PhoneNumber
```

FROM cus
WHERE Y REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';